# Regex for number between 0.0 to 0.999 onkeyup

Tags: javascript, regex, pattern-matching, keyup

I'm trying to validate a decimal number between 0.0 to 0.999 or .0 to .999.

I'm trying the below,

```
$('#num').on("keyup", function () {
    var value = $(this).val();
    var regex_cell = /0(\.\[0-9]{3})?/;
    if (!value.match(regex_cell)) {
        this.value = this.value.replace(this.value.slice(-1), "");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using regex you could convert to float and validate it.

```
var s = "0.999";
var n = Number.parseFloat(s);

if (n >= 0 && n <= 0.999) // 3 decimal positions only? s.length <= 4
{
    // valid
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The regex is

```
var regex_cell = /0(\.[0-9]{1,3})?/
```

Answer (score 0):

`var regex_cell = /0?(\.[0-9]{1,3})?/`

0 is optional.  Still, 0. would fail.  Blank would fail.  Best way is to do the evaluation with floats probably (use 'Number.parseFloat').  This is not a good job for a regex